# Create a Table for a user account in java using sql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am having issues running a statement in java that should give me a unique table for every new user account that is created. I get a syntax error on the Create Table statement and from what I have checked so far, everything seems to be in order. I am thinking there might be a bug in XAMMP or phpmyadmin which are the tools I am using for the database. Here is the code:

```
public static void CreateAccount(){



 try{
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 System.out.println("Driver loaded");

 Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection
         ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/users", "root", "");
         System.out.println("Database connected");


 Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
  statement.execute
  ("CREATE USER '"+user+"'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '"+password+"'; "+
           "CREATE TABLE "+user+" (AccountID int, FirstName varchar (255), LastName varchar (255), Age int); "
         + "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON USERS."+user+" TO '" +user+"'@'localhost';"

         +"INSERT INTO"+user+"VALUES (1, '"+FirstName+"' ,'"+LastName+"',"+Age+");");




}catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException a){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Can't connect to database");
a.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE mark (AccountID int, FirstName varchar (255), LastName varchar (255' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:734)
at SimpleJdbc.CreateAccount(SimpleJdbc.java:54)
at Basic.main(Basic.java:113)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow multiple statements in your database connection.  Add

```
?allowMultiQuery=true"
```

to your connection string.

Or you could build a stored proc to do it for you.

However, you also need to lookup SQL Injection, tons of info on SO about that.

Third, why in the world do you want a table per user?

Comment: How exactly would I have to rewrite my code to get it to work?

Comment: don't have MySQL handy, but I think you add the ?allowMultiQuery=true" at the end of your connection string.  (If that's what you're asking)

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't really seem to work. I don't have a connection string, I just have a direct connection as you can see in the code I provided

Comment: Sorry, connection string was misleading.  I mean your connection statment:  jdbc:mysql://localhost/users?allowMultiQuery=true.  Again, I can't test it right now, so the syntax may not be perfect.

Comment: Not working for some reason. I think I will just create separate statements and run them all together as method. Seems the easiest way now